# Issues in running matlab from python

Tags: python, matlab, nonlinear-optimization, scipy-optimize

I am trying to solve an optimization problem where the input to the function to be optimized is a 12x1 vector and the output is a matrix of size 6x3.
I tried solving this using fsolve, root solvers from scipy.optimize
but got the following error:

```
fsolve: there is a mismatch between the input and output shape of the 'func' argument 'f'.Shape should be (12,) but it is (6,3).
```

but this problem can be easily solved in matlab using fsolve.
So i created a very simplified version of the original problem :

```
import matlab.engine

eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()

import numpy as np

func = lambda x: x[0]**2 + x[1]**2 -25

eng.fsolve(func,eng.rand(2,1))
```

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

    File "C:\Users\reach\anaconda3\envs\MyEnv\lib\site- 
    packages\matlab\engine\matlabengine.py", line 66, in __call__

    out=_stdout, err=_stderr)

    TypeError: unsupported Python data type: function
```

Answer (score 0):

Data type mapping from MATLAB to python and viceversa can be VERY troublesome, and it seems `lambda` functions are not recognized properly by the matlab engine as function handles. The official documentation does not provide useful informations about callable conversion, as only [these standard data types are natively supported for passing.](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/pass-data-to-matlab-from-python.html)

If defining a proper function (with `def`) does not help, I would suggest to code a `.m` file with your matlab code (maybe with standard data type parameters) and run it from python as explained [here](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-user-script-and-function-from-python.html).